# changing fontFamily conditionally

Tags: javascript, css

I wish to change the font-family of a paragraph continuously after every 1 second.. Here is my non-working code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src = "jquery.js"> </script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var idee = document.getElementById('p1');   

    changeFont();
}); 

    function changeFont()
    {
        if(idee.style.fontFamily == 'times')
        {
            idee.style.fontFamily = 'courier';
        }
        else if(idee.style.fontFamily == 'courier')
        {
            idee.style.fontFamily = 'times';
        }

        setTimeout(changeFont, 1000);

    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="p1">This is some text.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

So.. what am I doing wrong? How to change font conditionally?

Comment: for learning purposes...

Comment: no.. Problem solved.. I had to declare the font in paragraph styling before using it in javascript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code works fine..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    function changeFont()
    {
    var idee = document.getElementById("p1").style.fontFamily; 

        if( idee == 'times')
        {
   document.getElementById("p1").style.fontFamily = 'courier';
        }
        else if(idee == 'courier')
        {
   document.getElementById("p1").style.fontFamily = 'times';
        }

var int=setTimeout(function(){changeFont();},1000);

    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="    changeFont();">
<p id="p1" style="font-family: times;">This is some text.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it did! I still don't know what I was doing wrong (Other than declaring variable inside anonymous function)

Comment: @BLOB - There were Silly Mistakes like 1) var idee declaration 2) defining  p1 fontfamily at the starting (this was the key)

Comment: aaawww... I get it.. I had not defined the fontFamily! thanx @ameya

Comment: I assumed since default fontFamily is 'times', everything will work fine.. But no, We should define it before using it...

Comment: @BLOB - If you are using any elements defining them by yourself is always a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

you have set var idee in the anonymous function inside the document ready but you're not passing it to changeFont, you're just calling changeFont and hoping that it's there on the global namespace.

try this first:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src = "jquery.js"> </script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var idee = document.getElementById('p1');   

    changeFont(idee);
}); 

    function changeFont(idee)
    {
        if(idee.style.fontFamily == 'times')
        {
            idee.style.fontFamily = 'courier';
        }
        else if(idee.style.fontFamily == 'courier')
        {
            idee.style.fontFamily = 'times';
        }

        setTimeout(function() {changeFont(idee)}, 1000);

    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="p1">This is some text.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: no.. i copied the entire code, still font is not changing.. Some problem lies in the conditional checking of fonts.. How to properly check which font family the element is using?

Answer (score 0):

`idee` is being declared inside the anonymous function.

It will not be visible in changeFont.

```
<script>
var idee;
$(document).ready(function() {

    idee = document.getElementById('p1');   

    changeFont();
});
```

AND

`setTimeout('changeFont()',1000);`

Comment: Put a breakpoint in changeFont() and see if it's being called every second. Also examine the CSS properties of #p1 when you update `fontFamily`

Comment: the conditional check for font family code is the error... I deleted that part and added alert() in theere and the changeFont function was called... what to do ?

Comment: I fixed the anonymous function calling.. but still font is not changing

Comment: `alert(document.getElementById("p1').style.fontFamily);`

is showing blank javascript alert..